# And so I slew him for the presumption

Tags: story-identification

This quote has been in my mind for a while, thinking about using it in my own writings.

> [A god has done something gods tend to do, but relating to the speaker], and so I slew him/it for the presumption.

I can recall reading it, but I can't recall where. Given my own tastes, it's probably fantasy rather than science fiction.

The quote was somewhat early in the work, and the speaker wasn't the primary protagonist, but was a powerful person. The god might not have been an actual god, but it and it's kind were generally considered to be unassailable by the class of person the speaker was.

The thing that the god did wasn't something generally regarded as offensive. As in, a god requiring prayer, not something costly as sacrifice.

Google couldn't help me, though my google-fu might be lacking.

It was a book, fantasy novel. Belgariad-ish, but I read that one in Dutch only, so it can't be the source of the phrase. Similar vibes, though. It is at least 15 to 20 years old at the time of this writing.

Primary identifier of what I remember was someone slaying a presumably more powerful being, rather than a lesser one like most of the comment examples of similar phrases.

Any ideas? I feel like just the name of the work, the rest of the context will suddenly be there for me.

Excluded works:

- Bible (I'd have recalled it in dutch instead of english)
- Belgariad (same, and I've read it enough that I know it wasn't.)

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! A look at this [checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) might help jog your memory and unearth a few forgotten details that could help identify what you're looking for

Comment: You might also find the list of works at [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KillTheGod) (obiligatory TVTropes warning!) helpful in jogging something.

Comment: There is a lot of similar lines in A Song of Ice and Fire series. "So I hanged him for his presumption", "So I had him flayed for his presumption", "So I had them whipped for that presumption", "So he tore his tongue out for his presumption"  (Said about mute guy Ilyn Payne)...

Comment: It crops up in the bible and in various other old texts, it's a pretty well worn phrase, I don't know if you're going to find your own reference easily, sorry.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - And in this [commentary on Dante's Inferno](https://rb.gy/4yhueh) - *"Capaneus, having succeeded in gaining a footing on the summit of the walls of Thebes, in spite of the missiles that were showered down upon him, in a fit of arrogance defied the Gods to come to the assistance of the Thebans, whereupon **Jupiter hurled a thunderbolt at him, and slew him for his presumption"***.

Comment: I processed the checklist. Also read the TvTropes list on KillTheGod, but nothing rang a bell. I think the main identifying trait is that the slaying happens to a (perceived to be) more powerful being, where most comment examples here are of slayings of weaker beings explicitely. And my apologies if this turns out to be a pointless hunt. It's just one of those... niggling things in the back of my head that wants explanation. Bible is excluded from potential sources, since I'd recall the phrase in Dutch if that were the case. And I never actually read ASOAIF.

Comment: It doesn’t fit the rest of your criteria  well, but could this be Star Trek or some sort of Star Trek novel? Worf has a very iconic line about how the Klingons killed their own gods for being more trouble than they were worth.

Comment: I'd be very surprised, since I never read not watched Star Trek myself.